# Is There a Toilet Plate Designed to Secure Traditional Floor Design to Back Wall

Tags: bathroom, toilet, flange

Is there a solution available which enables someone to secure a traditional floor mounted toilet bowl adequately to the wall behind it?

I would love a  commercially produced oversized toilet plate which is designed to be rigid enough to prevent movement and attaches to the back wall with a molded bracket or something.

I'm absolutely open to sell-fabrication of some wood or metal design which is either common or someone had to do it once a decade ago.

I know that the impulse for most people will be to address the reason why a floor mount is not an option, doing so to determine whether or not I failed to consider a more common alternative floor mount solution. To avoid the dissertation-sized post which would result if I felt compelled to justify this requirement with all the reasons each alternative floor mount solution would not be possible or adequate, I'm going to ask that for this scenerio that the following assumptions are absolute:

- There are no workable options to adequately secure the base to the underlying floor
- The use of a design-built wall mounted toilet will not work
- The solution must use a modern design traditional floor mounted toilet base built to current plumbing standards and dimensions

If there are no solutions to choose from here, I'll eventually answer my own question and explain what I ended up designing, fabricating, installing, and how well the design worked.

Thanks

Comment: This question is not only extremely difficult to answer, but unfortunately is of no interest to anyone not in the identical circumstances as BigNutz. - This is not to say that he shouldn't have asked it, it's just that it's more entertaining than useful.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri A I Breveleri, you basically just summed up the story of my life. That concept has been a pretty consistent trend in my life!!

Comment: *Just use Bignutz to bolt it to the floor*. What is wrong with your floor and why is not addressing a proper floor/foundation for a toilet not an option. Otherwise there is no product i know of that is made for attaching a floor mounted toilet to a wall. Have fabrication shop make you 1/4" steel plate, kind of like a very large angle iron. Plate on floor welded 90 degrees at wall and up the  wall bolted to studs.  Hole for toilet drain and holes tapped to except threaded bolts to mount toilet. Have them add large steel triangle  gussets to prevent flexing. Should only be a few hundred dollars.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I love every part of that answer!! I'm going to probably end up doing something very similar to what you described. I've got a shop close to my house which has been my plan to use. When I get it made, have the design patented, scale up manufacturing in 4 countries, and make this the trendy must have toilet mount around the world... Well, i won't forget you, Alaska Man i won't forget you!!

Comment: If you are going to go nutz, go bignutz or go home. I look forward to my profit dividend percentage. It was a bit tongue-in-cheek but if you like it I’ll write it up as a proper answer when I get home.

Comment: I like Alaska man’s answer but I am 6’5” and I might need a ladder to climb up on that guy a toilet of 7-9” taller less splashing when us guys pee.